# How to use `quick-error` with boxed error types?

Tags: rust

#### Problem Description

I am trying to use quick_error like this:

```
#[macro_use] extern crate quick_error;

use std::error::Error;
use std::io;

fn main() {
    quick_error!{
        #[derive(Debug)]
        pub enum MyError {
            Io(err: io::Error) {
                cause(err)
            }
            Any(err: Box<Error>) {
                cause(err)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Even though there are many other error variants, the one I am most interested in is one that can handle any kind of error by boxing it.

However, the code above does not work for the boxed type:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::error::Error + 'static: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:11:23
   |
11 |                 cause(err)
   |                       ^^^
```

When looking at the generated code (using `cargo expand`), it becomes a bit more evident why that is:

```
#[allow(unused)]
impl ::std::error::Error for MyError {
    [...]
    fn cause(&self) -> Option<&::std::error::Error> {
        match *self {
            MyError::Io(ref err) => Some(err),
            MyError::Any(ref err) => Some(err),
        }
    }
}
```

A `&Box<Error>` does not automatically become a `&Error`, unless you call `err.as_ref()` on it specifically.
Thus the code below works, and I tried it by just compiling the expanded, adjusted version myself using rustc.

```
#[allow(unused)]
impl ::std::error::Error for MyError {
    [...]
    fn cause(&self) -> Option<&::std::error::Error> {
        match *self {
            MyError::Io(ref err) => Some(err),
            // ------> note the *as_ref()* <------
            MyError::Any(ref err) => Some(err.as_ref()),
        }
    }
}
```

#### Question

**What can I do to make the above work ?**

#### Additional Notes

To me it would be viable to modify `quick-error`, however, it's not allowed to call `.as_ref()` on `&std::io::Error` for example, which seemed like a simple fix for `quick-error`:

```
#[allow(unused)]
impl ::std::error::Error for MyError {
    [...]
    fn cause(&self) -> Option<&::std::error::Error> {
        match *self {
            MyError::Io(ref err) => Some(err.as_ref()),
            MyError::Any(ref err) => Some(err.as_ref()),
        }
    }
}
```

The above causes this error:

```
error: no method named `as_ref` found for type `&std::io::Error` in the current scope
  --> expanded.rs:91:50
   |
91 |                 MyError::Io(ref err) => Some(err.as_ref()),
   |                                                  ^^^^^^
   |
   = note: the method `as_ref` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied: `std::io::Error : core::convert::AsRef<_>
```

And it really makes me wonder why I can't use `&std::io::Error.as_ref()` on any reference, considering it becomes a reference to an implemented trait automatically otherwise. Maybe it's syntax I am missing to state the intend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`as_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html#tymethod.as_ref) is provided by the [`AsRef`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html) trait. Notice that `as_ref` receives `self` by reference (noted `&self`), so in order to call it on a `&T`, `T` must implement `AsRef`. `std::io::Error` does not implement that trait.

However, there is another trait that looks a lot like `AsRef`: [`Borrow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html). `Borrow` provides a single method, `borrow`, with the same signature as `as_ref`. `Borrow` also has a different set of implementors; notably, it has `impl<T> Borrow<T> for T where T: ?Sized`. This means that for *every type*, we can invoke a `borrow` method (provided that the `Borrow` trait is brought into scope with `use`) to obtain a reference to the same type. `Borrow<T>` is also implemented for `Box<T>`, so you can borrow a `T` from a `Box<T>`, and likewise for other pointer/smart pointer types.

```
#[allow(unused)]
impl ::std::error::Error for MyError {
    fn cause(&self) -> Option<&::std::error::Error> {
        use std::borrow::Borrow;
        match *self {
            MyError::Io(ref err) => Some(err.borrow()),
            MyError::Any(ref err) => Some(err.borrow()),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! I just incorporated this into a [PR for the quick-error](https://github.com/tailhook/quick-error/pull/28) crate.